# Selenium webdriver to make it lightweight (memory wise) without headless

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm wondering if there's any option for selenium webdriver (chrome) to be run statically such that I can't interact with the browser and am only looking for the display. Similarly, is there any settings in "options" for chromedriver to make browsers very lightweight?

Lastly, would it be possible to live-stream the automated browser and display it somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

For a static non-interactive display have you considered a screenshot? That can open in a browser window or in any photo editor..

To decrease memory there are lots of options.
Have a look at [this link](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) for chrome command line options. If you search for memory there are 41 hits - should give you things you can try.  Potentially if you disable some of the features that could decrease chrome's foot print.

The last bit you inquire about remotely viewing chrome in another location. When you launch Chrome add this option:

```
--remote-debugging-port=9222
```

The in another browser open up http://<IP_for_RemoteChrome>:9222/
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62880082/elementnotinteractableexception-error-when-using-headless-option/62880402#62880402) for more info.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Not a screenshot, I want to live stream the browser in another program using python. Is 9222 specialized for selenium webdriver or?

Comment: try it and see :-)    if you click the more info link you can see a way to launch chrome with the required tag and just change the port. Fairly sure you can mix the port up if you need.